# Move all header files to /usr/local/include/<target>/

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I have a minor problem. I've created a program that I can install with the following command:

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

This works great but all .hpp files are then in `/usr/local/include`. Is it somehow posible to move this .hpp files to `/usr/local/include/<target>`?
So if I have a program called my_program, and let's say header file called `Timer.hpp`, is it posible to move this `Timer.hpp` into `/usr/local/include/my_program`?

I want to do this via automake and autoconf. If you look at `/usr/include` you will notice that there are a few directories for other programs as well. I want that, but in `/usr/local/include` of course.

I am also aware of `./configure --prefix=/path/my_program` and then, there is all in `/path/my_program`, but I don't want that. I want a directory with my program name in `/usr/local/include` and inside that directory I want all hpp files of my program.

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Automake, then right now you probably have a line like:

```
include_HEADERS = ...
```

The simplest way to fix this is to use the predefined `pkgincludedir`:

```
pkginclude_HEADERS = ...
```

This will use your package's name as the name of the subdirectory.

Or, you can introduce your own directory variable like:

```
myincludedir = $(includedir)/whatever
myinclude_HEADERS = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you are asking for a solution at the package level as Tom Tromey provided, or if you want a solution to be applied during configury.  If the latter:

```
configure --includedir=/usr/local/include/my_program
```

will set up the build to put include files in the specified path.  You can control the final destination of most files (indeed one could probably argue that the package is broken if not s/most/all/) with options passed to configure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking for solution at package level, as Tom Tromey provided.